# woo-commerce Product gallery disappeared, and light-box not working

Tags: woocommerce, product, image-gallery

I am using child theme of twenty-twelve, after updating woo-commerce to Version 3.0.9, product gallery just disappeared, only featured image is there. even light- box is not working.

I had overwrite it with woo-commerce product slider plugin, though it isn't working. what am i missing here? :/

Product page : 
https://www.turfleet-hire.co.uk/product/toro-procore-648/